# 2013 tacoma won’t start. Brand new plugs and fuel pump

Tags: toyota, starting, cranks-wont-run, tacoma

2013 Toyota Tacoma 6cyl.  Randomly won’t start it leaves me sitting when I go somewhere to hop back in engine will turn over and not start. I’ve changed fuel pump and new plugs.  Any ideas? I can sometimes get it fired up with spraying starting fluid in air intake.  Frustrating

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the "not starting" the reason you changed the fuel pump and plugs? How many miles on the truck?

Comment: Several things come to mind with this type of problem; 1)factory antitheft system disabling injectors, spark, starter, fuel pump, 2)intermittent spark, 3)intermittent fuel pump and/or pressure. Are you able to troubleshoot and separate possible factory antitheft problems from possible intermittent spark or fuel issues?

Comment: I’ll look into it.  It’s not throwing any codes or anything. So I’m game to figure it out.